# Printing specific lines of log file - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to print specific content of the file from the log..
for each line in the file - printing the whole line. instead of th

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:   
    for line in f:  
       if "Trace log :" in line: 
          print line
```

This works fine.

If I want to be more specific about the line : 
            `if "Trace log : {"request":{"http"":` then print the trace log content; getting an error.

```
if "Trace log : {"request":{"http"":
                        ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use this instead: `'Trace log : {"request":{"http"'` (note the single quotation). Or you can quote the *internal* `"`: `"Trace log : {\"request\":{\"http\""`

Comment: I have attached a sample log. i am getting the data which is before the trace log too. I want only the contents with the trace log..

Comment: Did you read my first comment?

Comment: yeah, read that. when i tried that it is printing the whole content (not only the trace log data)

Comment: You should modify the condition, `if 'Trace log : {"request":{"http"'` is **always** evaluated to `True`.

Answer (score 3):

@Maroun answered this is in a comment, I am writing an answer for future reference:

A string may not contain the quotation used to start it:

```
>>> 'foo' # OK
'foo'
>>> 'fo'' # Starts with ' and has ' inside, NOT OK
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Either use another starting quote or escape the inside quote:

```
>>> "fo'o"
"fo'o"
>>> 'fo\'o'
"fo'o"
```